# How to allow specific Methods for specific URLs which contain Regex/Wildcards too in Nginx?

Tags: regex, linux, nginx, proxy, wildcard

I have an Nginx and I need to allow access to Specific Methods for Specific URLs, what's more, is that these URLs contain Regex.

The requirements are as below:

```bash
/bill/<SOME_NUMBER_THAT_CHANGES>/verify --> GET & POST only

/bill/ipn/<SOME_STRING_THAT_CHANGES> --> POST only
```

My current configurations that don't work are as below:

```
server {
    server_name             foo.example.com;

    location ~ ^/bill/([0-9]+)/verify { 
        limit_except GET POST {
           deny all;
        }
        proxy_pass http://app:<PORT>/$1;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }

    location ~ ^/bill/ipn/([A-Za-z0-9]+) { 
        limit_except POST {
           deny all;
        }
        proxy_pass http://app:<PORT>/$1;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/foo.example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/foo.example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```

For instance, whenever I try to `curl` `foo.example.com/bill/540/verify`, it returns `404 not found`.

I've used the following links to create the above config:

- ["proxy_pass" cannot have URI part in location given by regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53353572/proxy-pass-cannot-have-uri-part-in-location-given-by-regular-expression)
- [Nginx to allow only POST requests for certain URL's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22127202/nginx-to-allow-only-post-requests-for-certain-urls#22203262)
- https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#limit_except

Question: Any idea how to achieve this?

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out:

```
server {
    server_name             foo.example.com;

    location ~ ([0-9]+)\/verify(\?status=.*)* {
        rewrite ([0-9]+)\/verify(\?status=.*)* /bill/$1/verify$2 break;
        proxy_pass http://app:<PORT>;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

        limit_except GET POST {
           deny all;
        }
    }

    location /bill/ipn {
        limit_except POST {
           deny all;
        }
        proxy_pass http://app:<PORT>;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/foo.example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/foo.example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```

The trick was capturing the parts I wanted and then passing them as variables such as `$1, $2, ...` in the `rewrite` section.

I used [This](https://regex101.com/) regex builder in PCRE flavor since it was mentioned in Nginx docs to make sure my regex is correct.